# Does bash add implicit quotes around value?

Tags: bash

I saw an example [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) that is like

```
#!/bin/bash
OF=/var/my-backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz
tar -cZf $OF /home/me/
```

What confuses me is how the `OF` variable is set to what seems to be a string but is not quoted? Does bash add implicit quotes around `OF`'s value? If so, does it add single or double quotes?

Comment: Quite the opposite: the last step in processing a command line is quote *removal*, where all syntactic quotes are stripped from the value. When you write `echo "foo bar"`, the echo command gets a single argument `foo bar`, rather than two separate arguments `foo` and `bar` if you hadn't used quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash does not add quotes automatically. `OF` gets the full path because  `/var/my-backup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz` does not have any spaces in it. You might think it does after `date` but in fact `$(cmd …)` runs the function in a "separate shell" and returns a string. In this case the string is "20150902" and the whole value that `OF` is set to is `/var/my-backup-20150902.tgz`.

Comment: Right, and generally it would be better to use the quotes around the expansion, in case the unexpected happens.

Comment: So does OF end up being a string? If so, that means any sequence of characters with no space inbetween is classified as a string even though no quotes around?

Comment: @JohnRobins Quotes have nothing to do with whether something is or isn't a string. They are used to tell bash how to interpret and expand characters.

Comment: @JohnRobins All non-array variables in bash are strings (unless declared as "integer" variables). But that designation does not mean what you are trying to make it mean.

Comment: You can escape a character using a backslash. Quotation marks simply mean to escape everything between them. `"foo"` and `\f\o\o` are exactly the same string value.